# SimpleXMLRPCServer does not support methodSignature?

Tags: python

I'm implementing XMLRPCServer following "[Standard Python Library by Example](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/SimpleXMLRPCServer/)". I want client to be able to see method signatures, and I expected that

```
proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://%s:%s' % (host, port))
print proxy.system.methodSignature('list')
```

(client code) will show me method signature.

However it returns "signatures not supported"

Here is the code from [SimpleXMLRPCServer](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py):

```
def system_methodSignature(self, method_name):
    """system.methodSignature('add') => [double, int, int]

    Returns a list describing the signature of the method. In the
    above example, the add method takes two integers as arguments
    and returns a double result.

    This server does NOT support system.methodSignature."""

    # See http://xmlrpc.usefulinc.com/doc/sysmethodsig.html

    return 'signatures not supported'
```

Is there an *easy* way to enable method signatures? 
or SimpleXMLRPCServer really does not support them? Is there implementation that does support methodSignatures?

Would be good to know: why system_methodSignatures method is included if server does not support it? XMLRPC specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register introspection functions.

Read more here: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/SimpleXMLRPCServer/#introspection-api

Or see this solution for Django: http://code.google.com/p/django-xmlrpc/wiki/MethodSignatures

Comment: proxy.system.listMethods() works as expected, but methodSignature does not

Comment: Nice link: "SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCDispatcher, doesn't support the system.methodSignature() method". Thank you!

Comment: djc - I'm willing to vote on your django link, but I cannot vote on your answer. Could you edit your answer to include django link, please?